# Matching an apostrophe only within a word or string

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a Python regex that can match `'didn't'` and returns only the character that is immediately preceded by an apostrophe, like `'t`, but not the `'d` or `t'` at the beginning and end.

I have tried `(?=.*\w)^(\w|')+$` but it only matches the apostrophe at the beginning.

Some more examples:

`'I'm'` should only match `'m` and not `'I`

`'Erick's'` should only return `'s` and not `'E`

The text will always start and end with an apostrophe and can include apostrophes within the text.

Comment: What does "within string" mean? What kind of text are you matching against?

Comment: @anubhava If input is just 'a' it shouldn't match

Comment: `r"\b'\w"` might work, but it might not or it might not be optimal because we don’t know what kind of input you could get.

Comment: @Ryan only apostrophe with a string like `'I'm'` should return `'m` and not `'I`

Comment: So is the text always going to start and end with a single quote? Is it always going to contain a single word?

Comment: @Ryan that's correct. The text will always start with an apostrophe and end with an apostrophe and can include an apostrophe within the text.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/LDVyia

Comment: You don't even need regular expressions, then: `text[1:-1]` will remove the outside apostrophes. `text[1:-1].find("'")` to get the index of the apostrophe or `None` if there isn't one.

Comment: @Ryan: Exactly what [my demo above](https://ideone.com/LDVyia) shows. However, if there can be more than one `'`+letter a `re.findall` will be handy.

Comment: re.findall("[^\s+]('[^\s']+)", input)

Comment: @Erick Have you tried my code above? Does it work?

Comment: Example by @WiktorStribiżew worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Erick: I posted my solution, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match an apostrophe inside a *whole string* = match it anwyhere but at the start/end of the string:

```
(?!^)'(?!$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iPWzpK/1).

Often, the apostophe is searched only inside a *word* (but in fact, a pair of words where the second one is shortened), then you may use

```
\b'\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iPWzpK/2). Here, the `'` is preceded and followed with a word boundary, so that `'` could be preceded with any word, letter or `_` char. Yes, `_` char and digits are allowed to be on both sides.

If you need to match a `'` only between two letters, use

```
(?<=[A-Za-z])'(?=[A-Za-z])    # ASCII only
(?<=[^\W\d_])'(?=[^\W\d_])    # Any Unicode letters
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iPWzpK/3).

As for this current question, here is a [bunch of possible solutions](https://ideone.com/LDVyia):

```
import re

s = "'didn't'"
print(s.strip("'")[s.strip("'").find("'")+1])
print(re.search(r'\b\'(\w)', s).group(1))
print(re.search(r'\b\'([^\W\d_])', s).group(1))
print(re.search(r'\b\'([a-z])', s, flags=re.I).group(1))
print(re.findall(r'\b\'([a-z])', "'didn't know I'm a student'", flags=re.I))
```

The `s.strip("'")[s.strip("'").find("'")+1]` gets the character after the first `'` after stripping the leading/trailing apostrophes.

The `re.search(r'\b\'(\w)', s).group(1)` solution gets the *word* (i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, can be adjusted from here) char after a `'` that is preceded with a word char (due to the `\b` word boundary).

The `re.search(r'\b\'([^\W\d_])', s).group(1)` is almost identical to the above solution, it only fetches a *letter* character as `[^\W\d_]` matches any char other than a non-word, digit and `_`.

Note that the `re.search(r'\b\'([a-z])', s, flags=re.I).group(1)` solution is next to identical to the above one, but you cannot make it Unicode aware with `re.UNICODE`.

The last `re.findall(r'\b\'([a-z])', "'didn't know I'm a student'", flags=re.I)` just shows how to fetch multiple letter chars from a string input.